# Casimir operator of $SO(n,1)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there any book or paper where the Casimir operator (the generator of the center of the universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal U(\mathfrak{so}(n,1))$) on $SO(n,1)$ is given? I would really appreciate any comments.

Comment: Is Darth Vector your father by any chance?  Do you also know Hans Sylow?

Comment: Of course! Do you know my father? He is obsessed with proving the Riemann hypothesis; the math was always strong with him. Hans Sylow is a good friend of mine.

Comment: I assume you mean the quadratic Casimir, no? I mean, as you go up in rank, you get an increasing number of Casimirs. Have you paid due diligence with any of R Gilmore's overexplicit books?  In any case, start by embedding the Casimir of the SO(n) subalgebra in it.